# Updating large table (~6.5 million rows) & indexes

Tags: sql-server-2012, index, update

I'm trying to update a table with about 6.5 million rows in a reasonable amount of time, but I'm having some issues. We're adding a new column to an existing table and then setting a value for all rows based on the data in a column in another table.

```
UPDATE  TOP (20000) c
SET     c.NewColumn = ISNULL(p.Col1, p.Col2)
FROM    dbo.Child c
    INNER JOIN dbo.Parent p on c.FKId = p.Id
WHERE   c.NewColumn IS NULL
```

in a loop, like this [article](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2011/02/fastest-way-to-update-rows-in-large.html).  The update was still running after 2.5 hours.  I'm wondering if disabling indexes on `dbo.Child` would make an impact.  NewColumn has no indexes, nor will it, but there are other indexes (about 5) on `dbo.Child`

Is SQL Server smart enough to see that it doesn't need to update the other indexes (as they are not part of the UPDATE), or would we benefit from temporarily disabling the indexes while we do the update statements?

This is SQL Server 2012 but the DB in question is in 2008 compatibility mode.

Comment: May seem like a stupid question, but does the statement ever complete? If not, is there ever the occasion where `Col1` and `Col2` are both `NULL`?

Comment: @MarkSinkinson I haven't actually gotten it to run to completion.  I've canceled it after about 2.5 hours (or on the test server I was using when the Tlog used up all available space on the disk, which I've since remedied).  Col1 may be null, but Col2 is NOT NULL.

Comment: Did you check for blocking or what the wait type was? A lot of people jump to the conclusion that the update is slow because of I/O but in most cases I suspect it is being blocked, or waiting on logs to autogrow, or that the I/O is so bad that even without additional indexes to update it would still be slow. Seriously, unless the hardware is from the 80s, SQL Server should not take HOURS to update 6 million rows.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I haven't seen any blocking (the test server isn't being used by anyone currently), and also it takes a long time on my local workstation too which no one can access (copy of the same database).

Comment: How, exactly, did you *check* for blocking?

Comment: @AaronBertrand sp_who2

Comment: Focus on the spid that is actually running the update. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87575/how-to-determine-which-statement-is-blocking-an-update-in-sql-server/87577#87577 and http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/87260/1186

Comment: @AaronBertrand Doesn't look like there's any blocked following the first link you posted; also there is no one on the server and no automated processes running)

Comment: @Andy so analyze what it is waiting on. You can't just say "it's slow" and jump to the conclusion that you should disable indexes.

Comment: If you use one big batch that should take a lot less than 2.5h for just 6.5M rows. Even with 5 indexes. This is probably the fastest way to do it but it will lock the entire table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten about this question, sorry.  But we resolved the issue.  Using a MERGE statement reduced the query time to under an hour.  Disabling indexes had no effect.

Answer (score 2):

You say that the UPDATE is running in a loop and was still running after 2.5 hours. Did that loop update any rows at all? Was it the loop itself that was taking a long time or a single UPDATE statement? That is a somewhat important distinction and is currently ambiguous in the given information. However, here are some things to note based on things said in the question:

- No, SQL Server should not be updating indexes that do not use the new column
- Disabling indexes is not simply a matter of turning them off. It actually drops all of the index pages and keeps only the structure so that you don't need to run the full CREATE statement again. But re-enabling an index will have to rebuild it.

And here are some things to look for:

- Are there any UPDATE triggers on the `Child` table?
- What is the auto-growth setting on the transaction log? If set to a very low number it could be that the UPDATEs are impeded by a large number of auto-growth operations.
- Of those 5 indexes on the `Child` table, do any of them have `FKId` as the leading column?
- Have you tried lower batch sizes, or just 20k? I have seen several people randomly recommend large (10k - 50k) batch sizes for these types of operations without considering that not only does it limit the operation to that number, but it also hints to the Query Optimizer that the number is possible to hit in the first place. Hence, if there are only 5000 rows to find then it might keep looking past those to see if any others meet the `c.NewColumn IS NULL` criteria. And considering that the field is not indexed, all the Q.O. has to go on are the auto-generated statistics which don't tell it where to find the remaining `NULL` rows. Assuming that the first several iterations of the loop did succeed, SQL Server still has to find 20,000 rows that are NULL, out of the 6.5 million, by scanning as many as it takes, in no particular order, before it finds them. Hence the first few iterations probably happened quickly, but this type of operation slows down quickly as each successive pass needs to scan more and more of the records before it can find the 20,000 that meet the `IS NULL` criteria.

  So, two things to consider:

  - Start out with a small batch size, maybe 10 rows, and run that statement by itself (i.e. not in the loop). Does it come back? If not then you need to answer @Aaron's question about what the WAIT_RESOURCE is. If it does come back, increase the batch size to 100, then 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, and then 10000. It will take more loops to complete, but finding the required number of records to UPDATE will be easier to accomplish. Once you find a size that seems responsive, then you can run the loop again (I am guessing that somewhere in the 2000 - 5000 range is gonna work :)
  - Rather than get rid of indexes, you might actually want to create an index, temporarily, to support this particular UPDATE operation. A [filtered index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783(v=sql.100).aspx) (which was introduced in SQL Server 2008 so the compatibility mode shouldn't pose a problem) will allow you to target the remaining rows to update. Something like:

    ```sql
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Child_FKId_temp]
      ON dbo.Child ([FKId] ASC) -- you might need to include [NewColumn] ASC after [FKId]
      WHERE [NewColumn] IS NULL
      WITH ( FILLFACTOR = 100 );
    ```

Comment: Yes, rows were being updated.  We could see that if we queried counts against the table using nolock.